# Jquery .change() function behaviour

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have an input text box that I have wired up with the jquery 'change' function. I want to capture when the text of a text box changes. Currently, with my change function, when the user types in a text value and hits enter, the change event fires. This same text box can also be populated with a text value from a drop down menu elsewhere on the form. When the user selects the option in the drop down, the text value automatically populates the earlier text box value. However, though the value of the text box has changed, the change event doesn't fire. I'm trying to understand why? I need to capture when the value of my text box changes in either situation. I need to find the best solution for this and I'm trying to better understand the behavior of the change function.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried calling your change function from the select box onChange() or onBlur() events?

Comment: There is no native event that triggers when the value of an element is changed programatically as that would be counter intuitive, instead you trigger the change event when you change the value programatically.

Answer (score 1):

To capture the value of the textbox you are filling from a select list, just modify your function by adding something like $(this).val(); after you define where you want to dynamically add your text.

```
$(function(){
 $("select").change(function(){ // get value of select list on change, add this to next input
    var a = $(this).val();
    $("input").next(function(){
      $(this).val(a);
    });
    });
});

$(function(){
 $("input").change(function(){ // get value of your textbox on change, log to console
   var a = $(this).val();
   console.log(a);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "on input" instead of "on change" on text inputs, but a warning: IE8 doesn't work with "on input" so you could also use "on keydown"... is that what you are looking for?